# Unable to find BI Publisher Add in button in Word 2016

Tags: java, oracle, office-addins, bi-publisher

I am trying to install BI Publisher add on for Word on my system. 
Below is the configuration of my system:

- Windows 7- 64 Bit
- JRE - 64 Bit
- Microsoft office 2016 - 64 Bit
- BIPublisher - 32 Bit ( The 64 bit version is not installing, stating a message "Please use 32 bit version)

I tried using Java 32 and 64 bit versions, but I am still not seeing the BI Publisher tab in my word or excel.

Below is the Java version details on my machine. 
[image: Java configuration]

Steps I tried:

1. https://mani2web.wordpress.com/2016/06/18/issues-with-oracle-bi-publisher-with-microsoft-word-2016/
2. http://www.catgovind.com/obiee/solved-bi-publisher-tab-is-not-visible-in-ms-word/
3. http://www.redstk.com/bi-publisher-desktop-menu-ribbon-not-displaying-correctly/

Comment: Can you add the version numbers to what you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office 64 bit and BI Publisher 64 bit should match.

I was able to use BI Publisher 64 bit (Version: 11.117.0.79; MD5 Hash: e47ab8d8b0cd71a891c29ecc5df17cdd; Size: 237 MB (249,504,566 bytes)) with Word 2013 64 bit. Found my version by right clicking install file and reviewing properties. Their website lists 11.1.1.7 (I really don't get how disorganized Oracle is)

Also, may want do downgrade your JRE Last I was using was 7 Update 45 (7.0.450.18). Every time Oracle updates stuff, it becomes incompatible with nearly everything else.

Many versions available here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-publisher/downloads/index.html

Good luck!

Comment: Even though my machine is 64 bit windows and office is also 64 bit, the installer for 64bit BI Publisher is not running. It says use 32 bit only. So I am not even able to move ahead with installation.

Comment: Have you tried searching MyOracleSupport for the problem?

Comment: Not sure what worked exactly, but I uninstalled the BI publisher I downloaded from my workplace download center and installed the one from the list you mentioned. (11.1.1.7 32 bit). Now I am able to use the plugin without issues. ! thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the all programs (Start menu)
- Expand the Oracle BI Publisher Desktop (sub-menu)
- Click on "Enable or Disable Template Builder"

Then the BI Publisher will be displayed in the Word 2016 menu.

Answer (score -1):

I have this issue too but found the solution (I hope it'll be useful for you):

- After installing BI Publisher, enter to Word, go to FILES-> OPTIONS -> TRUST CENTER -> TRUST CENTER SETTINGS-> COMPLEMENTS, AND THEN, UNCHECK OPTION (Deshabilitar todos los complementos de aplicaciones).

After that, go to com objects and check BI Publisher.

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QlNR.png]